# Outlook 2013 crashing when opening .pst file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

So we've been having [this issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/outlook-2013-crashes-when-opening-pst-file/ccac97c2-f772-4da4-a4a2-9a19abdaf2be?rtAction=1440079254427) with Outlook recently which seems to have stumped Microsoft answers for over a year and a half, the most recent post being the one posted by one of our people.

List of attempted troubleshoots:

Multiple PSTs tested

Launched in safe mode

Ran Outlook repair tool

Ran office repair tool

Single user affected

Disabled all add inns

Doesn't crash when doing anything else

No other office programs experiencing issue

Restarted PC

Tried alternative profile

Any ideas on how this issue could be resolved?

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: In addition, please [edit] your question to include what you have tried to resolve your issue. Your question should be standalone and complete and not require access to some other site to understand. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Point taken, i'd tried to check if linking to another site's question would be bad form, though of course just throwing the link out would get deleted